# Life ray life cycle method in JSR-186 and 168

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am newbie in Life-ray even portal application. I just started study last 15 days, and yesterday I attend an interview, they ask me following question, some of the question I answered also, but help me to understand about following questions.

What environment have you worked.
Answer: I was using eclipse IDE and plugin SDK(as per them it was not correct,probably I am wrong)

If we have a Page containing a text field and button, what will happen if I click on button. 
Answer: I asked it depends what framework we are using struts or spring. then they asked if you are not using any framework then,
Then i said Life-cycle methods of portlet( init, processAction, render, destroy)

as per them this was not correct also.

Please help me to understand the correct answer.

Is there any thing specific to life-ray portal, I am quite confused.

And is there any life cycle methods difference between JSR-186 and JSR-268.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What environment have you worked

That entirely depends one what they mean by environment as it could be programming environment (IDE, other tools, languages) or it could work environment (teams, methodologies, etc). Could you elaborate more on what they asked?

> If we have a Page containing a text field and button, what will happen if I click on button

Again this is really open ended, and depends on what code is written. However we assume that the button is linked to a form, who's action is to invoke the Portlets process action method, then that's would would happen. After that it would probably enter the render phase again, but it depends what code has been written inside the portlet!

I personally think their questions are a bit generic, and they may have been looking for you to narrow down their questions more.

What do other people think?

Comment: Not entirely correct. An form which has set its action to an action URL will indeed call the portlet's processAction method on submission. After that, the render method is called on ALL portlets that are on the same page of the portlet that called the action (including this portlet itself).

It is also possible to trigger an event inside an action method. In that case, the event is being processed (by the portlets that are configured to be event processors) after execution of the action method, but before the render phase.